# How to access rtk-query slice data for given endpoint / from prepareHeaders?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have troubles solving common problem, that should be handled by RTKQuery.

When my application starts, it will load `configuration`. This configuration will contain stuff like baseUrl, some data used in headers etc.

I've used `createApi(...)` to create configuration slice:

```
export interface Configuration {
  baseUrl: string;
  language: string;
}

export const configurationApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "configuration",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/api" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    loadConfiguration: builder.query<Configuration, unknown>({ //the generic expects second arugment...
      query: () => "/configuration",
    }),
  }),
});
```

I want to use the baseUrl and language of the loaded configuration in the following request. The documentation points `prepareHeaders` as the right place to do it:

```
export const testApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "test",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "/api", //need this from configuration
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const state = getState() as RootState;
     // nees to get language from configuration
```

I cannot how to access the result from `configuration` inside the `testApi`

I cannot find in documentation / examples how to access the data for any endpoint in that matter.

Let's say we have endpoint `loadUser` :

```
endpoints: (builder) => ({
    loadUser: builder.query<Partial<UserResponse>, UserRequest>({
      query: ({ userId }) => ({
        url: "/api/user"
      }),
    }),
  }),
```

Is there easy way to access the latest data ( regarding of the user ID, just latest data for user endpoint ) ?
It seems like this should be trivial, but it seems it's not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const selector = api.endpoints.foo.select(argumentLikeInTheHook)
const result = selector(getState())
```

You can find the documentation on that [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#select).

But generally keep in mind that if no component is using that endpoint data, it will be cache-collected after (per default) 60 seconds.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exactly `api` is and where it comes from. I'd guess its the second parameter to the `prepareHeaders` function, which is of type `Pick<BaseQueryApi, "getState" | "extra" | "endpoint" | "type" | "forced">` and thus does not have a field `endpoints` 

Comment: @Alex `api` in that example is the object created by `createApi`. I assumed as this whole question here is about `createApi`, that should be obvious with that naming.